# Is there anyway to reset heap size in salesforce through apex?

Tags: apex

I am facing  error in my org. Need some suggestion how can I avoid it.

> Apex heap size too large:

Here is my code:

```
global class OutputFileBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    public Call_Plan_SCenario__c callPlanScenario{get;set;}
    public List<String> lstOfObjects ;
    public string[] fields;
    public string db_ObjectName;
    public Integer counter;
    public String str;
    public string nameOfFile;
    Output_File__c outputFile=new Output_File__c();

    public OutputFileBatch(Call_Plan_SCenario__c newObj,String objectName,Integer count){
         callPlanScenario=newObj;
         lstOfObjects = new List<String>();
         db_ObjectName = objectName;
         counter = count;
         nameOfFile = db_ObjectName;
        nameOfFile = nameOfFile.substring(0,nameOfFile.length()-3);

        outputFile.Name=nameOfFile;
        outputFile.Scenario_Id__c=callPlanScenario.Id;
        insert outputFile; 
        system.debug('db_ObjectName-->'+db_ObjectName);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

       str=Utilities.GetHeaders(db_ObjectName)+'\r\n';
       string[] fields=Utilities.GetQuery(db_ObjectName );
       String query = 'select '+ String.join(fields, ',') +' from '+ db_ObjectName;
       return database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope){

             system.debug('--Limits.getLimitHeapSize()-->'+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
             system.debug('--Limits.getHeapSize-->'+Limits.getHeapSize());
               for(sObject rec : scope){
                  str+=Utilities.GetRecord(rec,db_ObjectName);
                }
                scope.clear();

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
                Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment();
                myAttachment.Body = Blob.valueOf( str );
                myAttachment.Name = nameOfFile +'.txt';
                myAttachment.ParentId = outputFile.Id; 
                myAttachment.ContentType = 'text/csv';
                insert myAttachment;

     }    
}
```

Comment: Go through [best practise to avoid apex heap size too large error](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004186&type=1). Post your code if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your goal is to create a giant string that represents all the fields of all the records of an object. Whatever you do in the peripheral code, that string will grow to consume all the heap (if it doesn't hit the 6,000,000 character string length limit first) if you have a large number of records (and made worse if you large amounts of data per record). Attachment bodies also have size limits.

I suggest change to chaining a series of these batchables where each one handles a limited number of records and creates its own attachment.

Comment: Yes I am attaching records more than 1 lakh. My user wants only one attachment for this big file. File would be around 15 mb. Can you give another suggestion how can I process further. For a while I am passing a single object in my parameter that contains records more than 1 lakh

Comment: @Jill_sfdc What your user wants may not be possible so you may have no choice but to re-negotiate the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Heap is generally caused by querying too many objects, creating too many objects, or storing too much state.

One common example we have is we wrap SObjects with our own classes when calling our services. This means, when a user calls our "retrieve" method to retrieve, say, Projects, we query for all the `Project__c` records, then for each `Project__c` we create a `new Project()`. That means we essentially double up heap for each record.

Another example is querying related fields. For example, if your query says `[SELECT Id, Account__r.Name FROM Project__c]`, each `Project__c` record will have it's own copy of the `Account__c` object. If you have 100 projects with a related account, and 2 accounts, you'll have 98 duplicates, so 98 records taking up heap.

If, instead, you query for `[SELECT Id, Account__c FROM Project__c]`, as well as `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Project__c)]`, then that's an extra SOQL, but significantly less heap.